# Import Error: Rasa Core

Tags: python, chatbot, path-variables, rasa-core

I am trying to run the chatbot on windows 10. Python version I am using is Python 3.6.6. I installed rasa-core using `pip3 install rasa_core` and the installation was completed.

But every time I run my code, I get `ImportError: No module named rasa_core.policies.keras_policy.`

here are the import libraries:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import argparse
import logging
import warnings
import csv 
import pandas as pd
import unicodedata

from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy
from rasa_core import utils
from rasa_core.actions import Action
from rasa_core.actions.forms import FormAction
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.channels.console import ConsoleInputChannel
from rasa_core.events import SlotSet
from rasa_core.events import AllSlotsReset
from rasa_core.featurizers import (
    MaxHistoryTrackerFeaturizer,
    BinarySingleStateFeaturizer)
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_core.policies.memoization import MemoizationPolicy
from rasa_nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter
```

How can I get rid of `Import Errors` related to rasa-core?

Comment: Try reinstalling rasa-core using "pip install rasa-core", as the support libraries for rasa-core requirement.txt is extracted using pip.

Comment: or even `pip install --upgrade rasa-core`

Answer (score 1):

What version of `rasa-core` are you using?
For e.g. on my mac Below are versions.

```
pip freeze |grep -i rasa
rasa-core==0.8.2
rasa-core-sdk==0.11.4
rasa-nlu==0.11.4
```

for `rasa-core==0.8.2` class KerasPolicy is in 
`python3.6/site-packages/rasa_core/policies/keras_policy.py`.

Hence you would import it using,

`from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy`

However, if you are using latest version `rasa-core`.  for e.g.

```
pip freeze |grep -i rasa
rasa-core==0.12.0a3
rasa-core-sdk==0.11.4
rasa-nlu==0.13.3
```

Then class KerasPolicy is in 
`/python3.6/site-packages/rasa_core/policies/keras_policy.py` .

Hence you would import it using
`from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy`

It appears that you are using an older version of `rasa-core` and trying newer versions based example.

You need to upgrade both `rasa-core` and  `rasa-nlu`.

[Here's link to latest requirement.txt](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial/blob/master/Full%20Code%20%5BLatest%20release%20of%20Rasa%20NLU%20and%20Rasa%20Core%5D/requirements.txt) that you can download. 
After that simply run  following to get dependencies installed along-with `rasa-core` and  `rasa-nlu`.

`pip install -r requirement.txt`

Comment: There is no difference between the import statements.